# Adding Soap Message Header for every request in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

In my old asmx web services  I used to have AuthHeader which contains the UserName & password and the AuthHeader is mandatory for every web method request. User will send his username & password using this AuthHeader and I will validate the request with the Username & password.

How can I ahieve the samething with WCF as webservice hosting in IIS with **basicHttpBinding** binding? Is there any way to make user mandatory to send AuthHeader with username & password?  
 ,
nRk

Answer (score 1):

You can uSe below code to pass username and password:

```
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "testuser";
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password10";
```

And you need to set the security mode as transport.

Comment: Thanks lucene, but when i am using basicHttpBinding, how can I make security mode to transport?

Answer (score 0):

Please see if below link helps you out:

[Use Username Authentication with Transport Security in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649647.aspx#Step9)